# Exception System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005) error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Services' does not exist in the namespace 'Cnbp.Cbk'

Tags: sharepoint, webforms, .net-4.8, gac, ascx

I work on a webForm project (.NET FrameWork)
And I have this exception :

```
<!-- System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a1f84433\8a878a8d\App_Web_genericusercontrol.ascx.9c4a4a40.c8huzmqq.0.cs(180): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Services' does not exist in the namespace 'Cnbp.Cbk' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
   at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at Cnbp.Cbk.FrontOffice.ContainerClient.Controls.SubGenericUserControl.GenerateBlocks(Boolean isReadOnly, Boolean editByBlock, LinkButton calcButton, ContributionBlockUserControl& blocCtrlContribution)
   at Cnbp.Cbk.FrontOffice.ContainerClient.Controls.SubContainerUserControl.BindControls() -->
```

.the DLL in question is already exists and is well referenced on the project but is not detected during the live ascx compilation

.PI: the DLLs are in the GAC

.I tried lots of solutions but none worked, someone has a solution please. Thanks in advance.